# (C++) Taking each char of a string and putting it into an array and getting the size of said array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character

```
cout << "Input text:\n";
cin >> tex;
```

take `tex` and put it into an array of whatever size?

for example, if I inputted `"hello"`, get an array that is something like

```
array[x] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}
```

I would then have a for loop that performs something on each letter (which I know how to do) but then how do I make it stop at the end?

Comment: If by *string* you mean *std::string*, then you can use [std::string::data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data).

Comment: If the variable `tex` is a `std::string` object then you basically already have what you want. Can you please elaborate on your problem? What is the actual problem you are attempting to solve?

Answer (score 1):

for a standard string, use below.

```
cout << "Input text:\n";
cin >> tex;
for(std::string::iterator it = tex.begin(); it != tex.end(); ++it) {
    //your work
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < tex.size(); i++){
    cout << tex[i];
}
```